# ASP.NET Core MVC models - SqlException cannot insert explicit value for identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a `Stick` class that has a relationship with the `InventoryItem` class. I have a code that has a bunch of sticks. I loop through the sticks to create each individual `Stick` and assign the `InventoryItem` to that stick.

However when I try to save the `DbContext`, I get an error of

> SqlException for Identity Column for table InventoryItems.

I don't understand why, since the `InventoryItem` is already create before all of this. All I did was passing the `InventoryItem` back and forth from the view model and the view.

Please see the image below. If I remove the highlighted line of code, then `DbContext` will be able to save and my `InventoryItem` for the sticks will be Null.

Please see more code references below and advise. If you need more info please let me know. Thanks.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfWa.png)

Stick Class:

```
public class Stick
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
}
```

InventoryItem Class:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double GetLengthInInches => Math.Round(Length / 25.4, 0);
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class OptimizationViewModel
{
    public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
    public IList<Cut> TempInstanceCuts { get; set; }
    public IList<Stick> TempInstanceSticks { get; set; }
    public double[] Percents { get; set; }
    public int CutQuantity { get; set; }
    public double CutLength { get; set; }
    public int stickCount { get; set; }

    public OptimizationViewModel()
    {
        TempInstanceCuts = new List<Cut>();
        TempInstanceSticks = new List<Stick>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include any relevant `OnModelCreating` and update code. It's likely that EF doesn't think your `Id` key is generated by the database.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman my codes don't have OnModelCreating. I'll read upon it and see if it helps me solve this issue. Will report my finding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you manually set the `Id` value for `InventoryItem` entity. You should not do that as it is auto-generated. Just ignore it when you create this entity.

Comment: Hi, I have intended for it to be that way. I wanted to create the InventoryItem first, pass it to the View and then have that pass back to the StickController, which then create a bunch of individual stick and then map to their parent, the InventoryItem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple omission: if you have an `INT IDENTITY` column in your table, you need to add a `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation on the key column in your model class:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double GetLengthInInches => Math.Round(Length / 25.4, 0);
}
```

And if the `Id` of `Stick` is also an identity column, do the same for that column, too, in your model class.

That annotation simply tells EF that this column is an identity column which is handled by SQL Server and that EF should ignore any value you might have assigned to it, and not include that column into an `INSERT` statement.

**Update #2:** it appears that EF **Core** has a new default behavior to automatically assume any non-composite primary key is handled by the database as a "generated property". Thanks to @LazZiya for that pointer: [Generated value on Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-1)

Comment: I think the KeyAttribute class accomplishes the same, while also setting the PRIMARY KEY flag, assuming it's an integer column, for Code First.

Comment: If the column name is `Id` it is not necessary to use `[Key]` or `[DataBaseGenerated...]` to configure as primary key. As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations): "_By convention, a property named `Id` or `<type name> Id` will be configured as the primary key of an entity._"

Comment: @marc_s, A property named `Id` will be configured as primary key by default. and will have [value generated on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-1) "_By convention, non-composite primary keys of type short, int, long, or Guid are set up to have values generated for inserted entities, if a value isn't provided by the application._"

Comment: @LazZiya: interesting - thank you for that link - this is new in EF Core (this definitely isn't the case in the "classic" EF in .NET 4.x)

Comment: @marc_s I have added that line of code to the Id of InventoryItem class and Stick class. Deleted the database, recreate the migration, and update the database through package manager but I'm still getting the same error. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: @marc_s you are welcome :) btw, here is another helpful resource for [Code First Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in)

Comment: marc_s @LazZiya thanks for the documentation links, I will read upon it and see if it helps me resolve this issue and report my finding. If you have any other tips advise. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the primary key value of `InventoryItem` model manually, you need to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute.

```
public class InventoryItem
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
   public int Id { get; set; }   
   //other properties 
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#no-value-generation-1

Answer (score 0):

So I took the time to read some of these and decide to rewrite my classes. I found what really helpful was I need to add an extra property like the ForeignKeyID which did help me work with related data. such as:

```
public class Stick
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
   public int ForeignKeyInventoryItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the documentations.